# Sphinx Update attribute failure

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I need to know how we can resolve the update attribute failure if request comes from concurrently?. Actually we are using 10 sphinx server in load balancer and if try to update the some instant update in 10 sphinx server using update attribute, its getting failure any more than one of the 10 servers (it may be 4 or 5 or 6 sphinx server). So In application side, we cant able to show the status correctly which we have updated instantly, because its comes from load balancer. How can resolve this kind of issues?.

Please help us to close this issue or share your input.
What about RT index in sphinx?.

Comment: What error do you get when you're trying to update?

Comment: Just i did get -1 try to update using updateattribute() function in sphinx api. if we get -1, then we write a log failure in our server.

Comment: What do GetLastError() and GetLastWarning() return?

Comment: I added the error function whic you have mentioned above in production server, getting the following errors. Those following errors are comes while try to update in some time.

 Update Attribute Failed; Time 16:47:38:000000 Sphinx Warning:  Sphinx error: temporary searchd error: server maxed out, retry in a second
 Update Attribute Failed; Time 16:47:38:000000 Sphinx Warning:  Sphinx error: connection unexpectedly closed (timed out?)

 How we can resolve this kind of issues?.

Comment: Are your Sphinx servers overloaded? Otherwise if you have resources for handling higher # of simultaneous sphinx queris consider increasing the value of max_children or set it to 0 (unlimited). BTW what workers mode are you using? Fork or Prefork?

Comment: Actually i dont know whether its overloaded or not. But our sphinx server will serve 1 crore records per day. We have configured 25 in max_children value. I cant able to configure 0 value in max_children, because our system getting hanged and cant do it further. We are using thread mode in sphinx.

Comment: OK, then try playing with SetRetries() for your UPDATE queries - http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setretries

Comment: Always its returing "false" if try to call this function SetRetries() in our PHP Code and getting the GetLastError as "connection unexpectedly closed". Writter in Code. $SphinxObject->SetRetries(6,10000); $SphinxObject->UpdateAttribute(......); Pls let me know whether its correct or not

Comment: 10000 seems to be too much, usually it's few ms, 50-100 or smth like this. BTW do you have any crashes of searchd? Is there anything interesting in the searchd log?

Comment: As per your suggestion i changed 50ms to setRetries() function . But its not works and got updateattribute failed. let me clarify given steps whether its correct or not. Actually we written code steps : if($SphinxObject->SetRetries(6,10000) == false) {echo "SetRetries is not set"} else {$SphinxObject->UpdateAttribute(......);}  Always i am getting "SetRetries is not set" and return "false" as well as we didnt get any sphinx error and sphinx warning (if i set 50ms;). what kind of steps we need to take for Retries works?.

Comment: in SetRetries() $count should be not more than 8 and $delay not more than 1000. SetRetries(6,50) should be working. Probably it's a mistake to check what this function returns, because this is not supposed to return anything. I.e. don't do this: 'if($SphinxObject->SetRetries(6,10000) == false)' 
Just do $SphinxObject->SetRetries(6,50) w/o checking what it returns.

Comment: As per your suggestion we have given SetRetries(6,50), but its not worked even we didnt get the any sphinx error and sphinx warning error and same time updateattribute did get failed. So any other possibilities are there to fix this updateattribute failure.Because we are getting more failure on day. So pls help us to close it.

Comment: Kumaran, I think I'll be able to help only if I log in to your server and check how it works internally, otherwise we might be looking for the problem for months :) Please contact me at info@ivinco.com if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use real-time indexes as a replacement of the main+delta index creation method. They are helpful to reduce server workload and simplify index updating.

But you have to keep in mind following points, if you want to use them:

- Real Time indexes only perform good on small amounts of data (< 4 million data sets).
- To get better performance use multiqueries
- Prefix and infix indexing are not supported yet.
- MVAs are not supported yet.